# Redirected output to my source file thus lost my source

Tags: linux, bash, recover

I just tried to redirect my code output to my code file itself, all contents in my code file are gone, any methods to recover?

Comment: You'll just have to restore the latest version of your file from your version control system or from the latest backup, whichever is more recent.

Comment: With just a little editing, this question might suit April Fool's Day:  "I just tried to redirect my code output to my code file itself, all contents in my code file are gone.  Why doesn't this work?"  By the way, sorry about the lost file.  I have done the same, myself.  It's not much fun.

Comment: @fedorqui:  The question does not look like a duplicate to me.  The OP's output has overwritten, not input, but the script itself.  This is regrettable for the OP, but it is not the same as the other.

Comment: @thb I see. I understood the question as a "why this happened?", while it happens to be "what can I do to solve it?". In that case, it is not very much related to [so], but of [su] or [sf]. Anyway, just reopened it.

Comment: Heh, National backup should use this post as an example.

Answer (score 1):

What can you do to recover the file you overwrote? Virtually nothing as the disk blocks that were freed when `file` was truncated are likely the first ones overwritten.

What to do to avoid it? Use Version Control religiously (I prefer mercurial because it is the lightest for single-person projects).

You could also set the "noclobber" option in the shell `set -C` which will disallow

```
redirection_to > an_existing_file
```

with the message "cannot overwrite existing file". But don't do this. It is a generally bad practice because the one time you are in a shell without noclobber set, you will accidentally overwrite a precious file.

Comment: thanks a lot, set noclobber seems to be more practical to me, since I am not the admin.